# Is 'I'm treated' correct and common in this context?

Tags: meaning

If say one's mother is setting up and readying the table for dinner and then starts calling the family to gather for dinner. One of the family members says 'Not me mother, don't include me in, I'm treated (at a friends)'.

Is 'I'm treated' correct like this. His friend has treated him for dinner at his house.

Comment: Not particularly idiomatic.  One would wonder what disease you had been treated for.  You could say "Frank already treated me to dinner," or something of that nature.

Comment: I think it would perhaps be better to say "I'm being treated" instead of "I'm treated".

Comment: More than likely one would use a different phrase entirely, such as "I've already been invited to Bob's" or "I'm already a guest at Bob's"... Or even "Bob's treating me to dinner tonight". Simply saying "I'm treated" is never said, to my knowledge.

Comment: I've never heard "I'm treated," used as described by OP, in any part of the United States where I've lived. But it's a big world.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's technically correct.

for general usage, it'll be too minimal without context. for example, you could not just say "i'm treated at bob's" to open a new subject. without context it's more common to say "i'm being treated to dinner at bob's" since treated does not necessarily imply food.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Could you capitalise your answer properly, please?